# calculating the Optimal list of things

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics, dynamic-programming, probability

problem statement
There are 5 buckets. Each n[many] of different products. Each product can repeat multiple times in the same bucket and across the bucket also. We want to derive products which should be based on two conditions:

1. Products counts should be considerably high across the buckets
2. same Product should have a considerably high count in each segment

i want list of products which satisfies the condition.

I tried knapsack algorithms. By providing random weights and profits. It seems wrong approach

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It depends what is more important 1. or 2. You need to define a real evaluation/fitness/cost or however you wanna call it formula. What you can do already now is as long as you have 5 or more of the same product put 1 in each bucket. So you basically modulo 5 the products. For the remaining products it gets interesting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In linear time you can find:

- The total count of each products across all buckets
- The count of each product in the bucket which has the least of it

If linear time is too slow, in sublinear time you could estimate the same by sampling the buckets.

In either case, you have the information (or an estimate thereof) that you need to make a decision.

After doing the above, you need to decide how you want to pick products -- essentially how you want to trade off the min vs total per product.